# Program succeeds using OpenMPI but fails in call to MPI_Allreduce when using MPICH 3.2.1

Tags: mpi

I have a program that runs correctly when compiled with the OpenMPI library, but fails with an error in `MPI_Allreduce()` when compiled with MPICH 3.2.1. This occurs both on Linux and MacOS.

The relevant code is

```
typedef struct reduction_packet {
  double sig;               /* logev */
  double s_width;           /* starting width */
  double s_nsites;          /* starting nsites */
  double width;             // width of motif
  double nsites_dis;            // final number of sites
  double llr;               // LLR of motif
  double classic;           // true if Classic objective function
  double ID; /* Use a double so the MPI type handle is simple. */
} REDUCE_PACKET;

REDUCE_PACKET a_packet, best_packet;
...
MPI_Allreduce((void *)&a_packet, (void *)&best_packet, 1,
   reduction_packet_type, max_packets_op, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The root error on the MPI stack is

```
MPIR_Localcopy(100)......: memcpy arguments alias each other, dst=0x7ffeeadd2f80 src=0x7ffeeadd2fc0 len=72
```

My interpretation is that MPICH MPI is telling me that the variables a_packet and best_packet overlap because the length of the variable to be copied is 72 bytes, but the two variables are only offset by 64 bytes.

Each of these buffers is actually a struct composed of 8 doubles which accounts for 64 bytes. I could imagine there might be some padding to handle alignment, but the compiler seems to be happy allocating these two variables on the stack without padding. I've logged the addresses for `a_packet` and `best_packet`, and they match the addresses reported in the error message from `MPIR_Localcopy()`.

If I change the declaration for the two variables to

```
REDUCE_PACKET a_packet;
char foo[2];
REDUCE_PACKET best_packet;
```

the program runs without error on MPICH and OpenMPI.

Why does MPICH think this variable requires 72 byes rather than 64 bytes? Am I missing something in the MPI/MPICH documentation that would inform me that I'm responsible for this sort of manual padding?

Comment: a [MCVE] is required for more investigations.

Comment: meanwhile, you can print `MPI_Type_get_true_extent(reduction_packet_type, ...)` and compare the output between Open MPI and MPICH

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thanks the suggestion to check MPI_Type_get_true_extent() was the key to debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this type of error, double check the definition of the `MPI_datatype` passed as the 3rd argument to MPI_Allreduce():

```
MPI_Allreduce((void *)&a_packet, (void *)&best_packet, 1,
   reduction_packet_type, max_packets_op, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

It turned out that we had changed the definition of the underlying C datatype, `REDUCE_PACKET`, but hadn't updated the call to `MPI_Type_contiguous()`, establishing the size the `MPI_datatype`, `reduction_packet_type`.

Apparently MPICH pays more attention to potentially overlapping memory copies than OpenMPI does.